# Как заблокировать запросы с не доверенных ресурсов (сервисов)

Tags: asp.net-core

есть в контроллер контроллере метод на удаления (каких то данных по Id) и запрос идет с вьюшки у определенного контроллера. Как можно заблокировать запросы с других ссылок или постамана. Получается может любой человек сделать запрос и удалять данные

Comment: используйте аутентификацию клиента

Comment: [CORS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) вам в помощь